# Indicator class lower or class higher with ordinal data in R

Tags: r, ordinal-indicator

I have this persons whose performance can lower or raise. Suppose there are three categories, so ordinal data with classes: 1 = Low, 2 = Middle, 3 = High. I measure them at point 1 (df$start) and at point 2 (df$end). I want to know whether they became better (indicator value = 1), worse (indicator value = -1) or stayed even (indicator value = 0) (df_result$diff).

I have converted the data type to ordered and think I should use a logical statement, but I don't know how to do this in R. Anyone has an elegant way to do this?

```
df <- data.frame(start = ordered(c(1, 3, 2, 3)),
             end = ordered(c(2, 3, 3, 1)))

df_result <- data.frame(start = ordered(c(1, 3, 2, 3)),
                    end = ordered(c(2, 3, 3, 1)),
                    diff = c(1, 0, 1, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it, here's one solution

```
df <- data.frame(start = c(1, 3, 2, 3),
             end = c(2, 3, 3, 1))

df$diff <- ifelse(df$start-df$end > 0, "worse", ifelse(df$start-df$end == 0, "even", "better"))
df
  start end   diff
1     1   2 better
2     3   3   even
3     2   3 better
4     3   1  worse
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `case_when` from `dplyr` package:

```
df <- data.frame(start = ordered(c(1, 3, 2, 3)),
                 end = ordered(c(2, 3, 3, 1)))

library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(diff = case_when(start < end ~ 1,
                               start > end ~ -1,
                               TRUE ~ 0))

#   start end diff
# 1     1   2    1
# 2     3   3    0
# 3     2   3    1
# 4     3   1   -1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this arithmetically as well if the 'start' and 'end' columns are `numeric`

```
df$diff <- with(df, c(0, -1, 1)[((start > end) + 2 *(start < end))+1])
df$diff
#[1]  1  0  1 -1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(start = c(1, 3, 2, 3), end = c(2, 3, 3, 1))
```